# Wordpress Woocommerce refund via payment gateway is disabled in admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[image: ***enter image description here***]

As you can seen, right button is disabled.
How to enable this so that I can make refund from payment gateway.

Comment: Have you added necessary API keys for payment gateway? check this link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-refunds/

Comment: @GajjarChintan please give me more detailed explanation on this, because I am new on woocommerce.

Comment: Is the button disabled when the purchase is more than zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created your own payment gateway. you just forget to have refunds as a parameter in your constructor add that.

```
class WC_Gateway_pinelab extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
 public function __construct() {
 $this->supports             = array( 'products', 'refunds' );
 }
}
```

After it please add the below function in you same class file. Make sure below function must be under the class.

```
public function process_refund($order_id, $amount = null, $reason = '')
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: greate, now it's working fine.

Comment: You are welcome.. i guess you need the refund data as well. Like qty product name taxes etc..

Comment: Above function is not doing any thing in database

Comment: No they do the changes in database. Once you click on refund it will fire the data in database.

Comment: I am using the same function as it is above. Should I change anything.

Comment: No nothing is required. It will automatically did the changes in database

Comment: @Aki that's not going to happen for sure..status will change but no actual refund will happen automatically..manual refund will be required

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla there is one function where i did return you need to do the code in that function.